# Button to hide/show label

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I have a problem, I want a button that once you clicked it the label hides and if you click the button again the label will show. Help! Java Jframe

Comment: You should be more specific! and how us that you've at least tried something.. Then you will get help buddy,,

Comment: Show some your current code or what you tried so far. you must CO-laborate if you want help. Nobody owes you to solve your problems if you don't COlaborate.

Comment: [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) then simple change the state of the `visible` property of the `JLabel`

Answer (score 1):

you can create two components inside jframe and use actionlistener to detect button click.

```
public class MyFrame{
JFrame frame;
JLabel label;
JButton button;
public MyFrame(){
    frame = new JFrame("Sample");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    label = new JLabel("Message");
    button = new JButton("Click");
    frame.add(label);
    frame.add(button);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if(label.isVisible(true))
            label.setVisible(false);
        else
            label.setVisible(true);
    }
    });
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(200,100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setVisible(true)` and `setVisible(false)` will suffice. Altough if you want to make this `JLabel` behave in more customized way you may write custom `JLabel` you can also make it implements `ActionListener` and call `changeState()` every click.

```
class MyLabel extends JLabel {
    private boolean state;

    public void changeState(){
       state = !state;
       if(!state)
         setText("");//or "hide" -> setVisible(false);
       else
         setText("your text");//or show -> setVisible(true); 
    }    
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `setVisible`? Seems like a lot of extra for little gain

Comment: @MadProgrammer nothing at all, just showing more universal way in case the next question is: how to change color/text and few more things of JLabel when I click it or if there will be more states of this JLabel. Maybe I should keep it simple.

Comment: I'd still favor [composition over inheritance](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=composition+over+inheritance&oq=composition+over+inheritance&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.799j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8), but that's me

Answer (score 0):

i just provide some ideas (and not code) on how you can do this

firstly, you should have all the handles of the UI elements
example

```
Button button = ...
Label label = ...
```

then you should do up the code for the actionPerformed method 
using if/else such that the label will hide or show depending on a boolean variable